# .net MVC entity framework SaveChanges does not working

Tags: c#, .net, linq, frameworks, entity

I want to update my db like

```
                        var context = new asb_cardEntities3();
                        var query = db.WFileMaster.Where(q => q.ID == 
                                                        data.ID).FirstOrDefault();
                        query.SUBE = item.SUBE.ToString();
                        query.HES_NO = item.HES_NO.ToString();
                        query.DVZ_KOD = item.DVZ_KOD.ToString();
                        query.TUTAR = item.TUTAR.ToString();

                        //context.Entry(query).State = SUBE.Modified;
                        context.SaveChanges();
```

this, I did not get any error (all data come) I am new in this framework, I think problem is in context. But I did not find any solution.

Comment: Is your context really a EF Core DBContext? What is the value of "asb_cardEntities3()"?

Comment: it is my db   I used this for my conn (asb_cardEntities3 db = new asb_cardEntities3();)

Comment: you need to use DBcontext to save your data to table, Currently you are using "...db.WFileMaster.Where...", which needs to be changed to "...context.WFileMaster.Where..."

You can refer to answer given below by Nagraj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change db to context while retrieving the record in the second line.

```
var context = new asb_cardEntities3();
var query = context.WFileMaster.Where(q => q.ID == data.ID).FirstOrDefault();
query.SUBE = item.SUBE.ToString();
query.HES_NO = item.HES_NO.ToString();
query.DVZ_KOD = item.DVZ_KOD.ToString();
query.TUTAR = item.TUTAR.ToString();

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score -1):

Before saving changes update the table
something like that

.Update(x => x.Id== ID, object);  and then

save changes.